# Using listbox to filter items in listview

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Since combobox in vba cant do multiselect, is it possible to use listbox as a substitute to combobox in filtering multiple items in listview? In initialize, the listbox is not visible and i set a button that will show the listbox incase the user wanted to filter some things in the listview. And also set another button for "Apply filters" and will also hide the listbox when clicked, apparently when i open the listbox again the highlighted items are back to default (not highlighted) is there a way that the highlighted items will remain highlighted even if i hide the visibility of the listbox? And how? Appreciate your replies thanks!

The first photo is when i select items on my listbox and press apply.
Then second photo is when i open again the listbox the checked items are gone.

[![checked items][1]][1]
[![Open again][2]][2]

```
Private Sub LOB_List()
On Error GoTo ERR_Handler
    Dim sql As String
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Records As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim RecCount As Long
    
    
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    
    con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.206.88.119\BIWFO;" & _
                          "Initial Catalog=TESTDB;" & _
                          "Uid=user; Pwd=password1;"
                          
    sql = "select distinct lob from data_test"
    
    rst.Open sql, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    
    Records = rst.GetRows
    
    RecCount = rst.RecordCount
    
   
    For i = 0 To rst.Fields.count - 1
      
    Next i
    
    rst.Close
    con.Close
    
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = RecCount
        .List = Records
        .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Records)
        
    End With
    
   
    
ERR_Handler:

    Select Case Err.Number
    
        Case 0
        Case Else
        
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, Err.Number
            
    End Select
End Sub


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktvCl.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8PLq.png
```

Comment: Are clearing the list box and re-initializing it or unloading/reloading the form?  A quick test with setting the visible property to true/false doesn't unselect items for me

Comment: Always helps to post your existing code...

Comment: Hello, edited my post and input the codes, also attached a photo on my listbox when i checked the items and click apply (hide the listbox) and open again the listbox the checked items went unchecked again.

Comment: looking at the code above, you are reloading the values in the list box every time you call the line `.List = Records` and again when you call `.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Records)` any time you reload the the values to the list box it will lose which values were already selected (even if its the same list of values).  You'd need to either not reload the list box values or store the selected list box values in a variable and then reselect them using `Listbox.Selected(X) = True` where `X` is the index of the value to be selected